# How do I get the Data in Nodejs from another Execution Context

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer, executioncontext

I would like to take data from a website whenever it is changed. For this case I use MutateObservable.
As scraper I use Puppeteer because the data is changed every second. And for this I need a permanently open browser I think.

As server I use Nodejs. Maybe someone can tell me how to solve the problem and get the data from Puppeteer into my execution context of nodejs.

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const scraping = require('./scraper.js')

const port = process.env.PORT || 2099
console.log(`Der Server läuft auf Port ${port}`);

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port);

let plane = new scraping('3e0f90');
plane.startTracking();

console.log('Url: ', heli.getUrl());
```

scraper.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class Scraper {

    constructor(icao) {
        this.icao = icao;
        this.url = `https://tar1090.adsbexchange.com/?icao=${this.icao}`;
    }

    getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    async startTracking() {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(this.url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

        await page.evaluate(page => {

            var speedNode = document.querySelector('#selected_speed1');
            var ob = new MutationObserver(mutation => {
                var speedValue = mutation[0].speedNode.innerText;
                console.log(speedValue);
            });

            var config = { childList: true }
            ob.observe(speedNode, config);
            // And now the callback in line 26 is always fired if the data changes.
            // How do I get them into my node execution context ? I want to save them in a database.
        });
    }    
}

module.exports = Scraper;
```

Comment: Either you need to move your scraper into your node project or you need to get your scraper to send the data to the node app via an API that you write.

Comment: You can also use [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) to tranfer data from observer callback.

Comment: thanks guys! the answer from vsemozhebuty helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go this way: you can run your `app.js` from `scraper.js` and then send any data to child process

**scraper.js**

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const forked = fork('app.js');

// Set forked process event listener
// and receive messages from child
forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
});

//
// Your code here
// ...
// And when you need to pass some data
// to your child process, send it like this
forked.send({ hello: 'son' });
```

**app.js**

```
// Set process event listener and
// receive data like this
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
});

// If you need to send something to
// parent process, do it same way
process.send({ hello: 'daddy' });
```